# SQL Joining different tables structure (MSSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I have different tables and I want to join all the information. In my case I have a Product, Sales and Product definition table.

Product Table:

```
ProductID | Name
     1    | Product 1
     2    | Product 2
     3    | Product 3
```

Product definitions table:

```
DefID    | ProductID |  Column 1 | Column 2 | ....
001      |   1       |    text   |   text
002      |   1       |    text   |   text       
003      |   3       |    text   |   text
004      |   2       |    text   |   text
005      |   3       |    text   |   text
```

Sales Table:

```
SalesID | ProductID |  Sales
01      |   1       |    13
02      |   1       |    12       
03      |   2       |    1
04      |   2       |    4
05      |   3       |    2
```

I want to replace the information (e.g. Product definition -> Sales) which is not existing with a -1. and to create a query to get this view:

```
DefID    | ProductID |  SalesID  | Sales | Column 1 | Column 2 | ....
001      |   1       |    -1     |   -1  |   text   |   text
002      |   1       |    -1     |   -1  |   text   |   text   
003      |   3       |    -1     |   -1  |   text   |   text
004      |   2       |    -1     |   -1  |   text   |   text
005      |   3       |    -1     |   -1  |   text   |   text
-1       |   1       |    01     |   13  |    -     |    -
-1       |   1       |    02     |   12  |    -     |    -       
-1       |   1       |    03     |    1  |    -     |    -  
-1       |   2       |    04     |    4  |    -     |    -  
-1       |   3       |    05     |    2  |    -     |    -
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ee87)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select DefID, ProductID, -1 as SalesID, -1 as Sales,  Column1 , Column2 
from productDefinition
union all
select -1 as DefID, ProductID,  SalesID,Sales, '-' as Column1 ,'-' as Column2 
from sales
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `ISNULL` function:

```
select ISNULL(DefID, -1) as DefID, ProductID,
       ISNULL(SalesID,-1) as SalesID, ISNULL(Sales,-1) as Sales,
       other columns...
from
```

Comment: the question is about joining tables, not about NULL